# C# Interop Save to excel from datagridview without creating new file

Tags: c#, datagridview, office-interop

I want to make changes to an existing file named "Original" in the directory "C:\Users\Twiga\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Projects\MarkSheetSystem\Original.xls".

Currently, I am only able to save the data that I have exported from my datagridview1 to a new file but that is not my intention.

Below is the code:

```
private void btnexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing); 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null; 

        try 
        { 

            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet; 

            worksheet.Name = "Marksheet 1";

            worksheet.Cells[12, 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 


            int cellRowIndex = 10; 
            int cellColumnIndex = 1; 

            //Loop through each row and read value from each column. 
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 
            { 
                for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++) 
                { 
                    // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check. 
                    if (cellRowIndex == 0)
                    { 
                        worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText; 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(); 
                    } 
                    cellColumnIndex++; 
                } 
                cellColumnIndex = 1; 
                cellRowIndex++; 
            } 

            //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user. 
            SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog(); 
            saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
            saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2; 

            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
            { 
                workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName); 
                MessageBox.Show("The marksheet has been saved successfully!"); 
            }                
        } 
        catch (System.Exception ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        } 
        finally 
        { 
            excel.Quit(); 
            workbook = null; 
            excel = null; 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Save/Overwrite existing Excel file with Excel Interop - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055369/how-to-save-overwrite-existing-excel-file-with-excel-interop-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to an existing Excel File using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722339/writing-to-an-existing-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your task, it would be better to export data to Excel `Workbook` from the `DataGridView` underlying `DataTable` (e.g. `DataTable _dt = (DataTable)(datagridview1.DataSource)`) as shown in the following C# sample code snippet:

```
/// <summary>
/// export DataTable to Excel (C#)
/// </summary>
internal static void Export2Excel(DataTable dataTable)
{
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _appExcel = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _excelWorkbook = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet _excelWorksheet = null;
    try
    {
        // excel app object
        _appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // excel workbook object added
        // can be replaced with _appExcel.Workbooks.Open(...) 
        _excelWorkbook = _appExcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        _excelWorksheet = _appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

        // column names row (range obj)
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range _columnsNameRange;
        _columnsNameRange = _excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", misValue).get_Resize(1, dataTable.Columns.Count);

        // column names array to be assigned to _columnNameRange
        string[] _arrColumnNames = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            // array of column names
            _arrColumnNames[i] = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }

        // assign array to column headers range, make 'em bold
        _columnsNameRange.set_Value(misValue, _arrColumnNames);
        _columnsNameRange.Font.Bold = true;

        // populate data content row by row
        for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dataTable.Rows.Count; Idx++)
        {
            _excelWorksheet.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dataTable.Columns.Count].Value =
            dataTable.Rows[Idx].ItemArray;
        }

        // Autofit all Columns in the range
        _columnsNameRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

This will **significantly improve the performance by exporting the entire data row at once instead of doing it cell-by-cell**.

The only changes you have to make is to replace the line that adds new Workbook:

```
_excelWorkbook = _appExcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
```

with another one, opening the existing Excel File (e.g. "ExcelFilePath"), like:

```
_excelWorkbook = _appExcel.Workbooks.Open("ExcelFilePath",
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Hope this may help.